# Developing a ramdom qr code generator program

Tags: qr-code

Hello I am new and learning qr code technology. It is possible to create a program that can randomly generate qr code but with same url (information). Lets say different qr code every time a want to generate but with same url (information).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QR codes - same URL - different image - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493183/qr-codes-same-url-different-image-why)

Comment: Since you can actually "destroy" a part of the QR, you can randomly pick an area in the center of the code and randomize squares there. The more complex your code, the more squares. This would require som fairly good image manipulation skills, but would be a solution if it is very vital for you to have a random code every time. Finally you can dive deep into QRs and place a random hidden string.