# How to convert image of QR Code to proper QR code?

Tags: python, image-processing, qr-code

Let's say I have an image of a QR code. that I took with my phone called `in.png`. I would like to create a nicer looking version of the QR code (so everything is at perfect right angles, the output is only solid black/white, etc.) without changing the way the QR code looks visibly.

Here is my Python code so far:

```
from PIL import Image
from pyzbar import pyzbar

img1 = Image.open('in.png')
out1 = pyzbar.decode(img1)

import qrcode
output = qrcode.make(out1[0].data)
output.save("out.png", "PNG")
```

That's my input image:

[image]

And, that's my current output image:

[image]

Even though they both contain the same data, the QR codes look different visually (bottom right for example). I don't want this, I want the output file to be the same visual representation of the input QR code. Can somebody help me correct my Python code to achieve this?

Comment: It's more like 'write from scratch' than 'correct my code'. Do you have any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551110/why-dont-duplicate-qr-codes-look-the-same

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have the exact appearance as in your original input, you'll need to involve actual image processing, I'm afraid. I switched to OpenCV and NumPy, since array operations are much faster and comfortable to perform than with Pillow.

The workflow is quite simple:

1. Binarize, and "clean" the input image, e.g. using morphological closing.
2. Crop the actual QR code.
3. Resize the cropped part to the actual QR code dimensions, i.e. to `(25, 25)` here.
4. Resize that image to your desired output size, and maybe add white borders around if wanted.

That's the full code including some visualization overhead:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image as grayscale, get dimensions
img = cv2.imread('dawjk.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
h, w = img.shape

# Binarize image to get rid of aliasing artifacts (gray-ish colors)
img_bin = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morphological closing to get rid of artifacts
img_bin = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3)))

# Count white pixels per row and column to crop actual QR code
sum_x = np.sum(img_bin == 255, axis=1)
sum_y = np.sum(img_bin == 255, axis=0)
y1, y2 = np.argwhere(sum_x < w)[[0, -1], 0]
x1, x2 = np.argwhere(sum_y < h)[[0, -1], 0]
cropped = img_bin[y1:y2, x1:x2]

# Resize cropped part to actual QR code dimension (25, 25)
resized = cv2.resize(cropped, (25, 25))

# Resize to destination size
dst_size = (400, 400)
resized_dst = cv2.resize(resized, dst_size, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

# Add white borders of desired size
m = 40
output = cv2.copyMakeBorder(resized_dst, m, m, m, m, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=255)

# Just for visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1), plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Original image')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2), plt.imshow(cropped, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Cropped part')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3), plt.imshow(resized, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Resized to QR code dimensions')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4), plt.imshow(output, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Final output')
plt.tight_layout(), plt.show()
```

That's the visualization output:

[image: Visualization output]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.2
Matplotlib:    3.4.2
NumPy:         1.20.3
OpenCV:        4.5.2
----------------------------------------
```